# What are current CF9.02 Session Cookie Management Best Practices?

Tags: coldfusion, session-cookies, coldfusion-9

Common "best practice" for ColdFusion cookie session cookie management has been to implement something like this:

```
<cfset this.setClientCookies = false />
<cfif NOT IsDefined( "cookie.cfid" ) OR NOT IsDefined( "cookie.cftoken" )>
    <cfcookie name="cfid" value="#session.cfid#" domain=".#cgi.HTTP_HOST#" path="/test/sessiontest">
    <cfcookie name="cftoken" value="#session.cftoken#" domain=".#cgi.HTTP_HOST#" path="/test/sessiontest">
</cfif>
```

OR

```
<cfif IsDefined("Cookie.CFID") AND IsDefined("Cookie.CFTOKEN")>
    <cfcookie name="CFID" value="#Cookie.CFID#">
    <cfcookie name="CFTOKEN" value="#Cookie.CFTOKEN#">
</cfif>
```

depending on who you talk to.

Adobe then released http://www.adobe.com/support/security/bulletins/apsb11-04.html and later a fix for this original fix, which is talked about here: http://www.shilpikhariwal.com/2011/03/update-on-security-hot-fix-feb-2011.html

The original fix causes a lot of issues described here: http://cfsimplicity.com/4/coldfusion-security-hotfix-changes-session-behaviour  This fix (and a lot of other similar fixes on the web) work by modifying the cfcookie code above.

It's a year later and what I would like to know if what are people currently doing for CFID/CFToken management when running CF9.02 (ie, with the session fixation fixes applied.)

Answer (score 1):

Um, not using CFID/CFToken.  I have not used those client variables for years and instead use ColdFusion session management.  It is just too risky to trust those from the client (in my opinion).

The Adobe docs actually have a pretty good write up about managing client state: [Managing the client state](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/Developing/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec0c35c-7fef.html)

What is your case for still needing to use CFID/CFToken?

An excerpt from that Adobe article:

> A hacker who has the user’s CFToken and CFID cookies could gain access to user data by accessing a web page during the user’s session using the stolen CFToken and CFID cookies. While this scenario is unlikely, it is theoretically possible.
>
> You can remove this vulnerability by selecting the Use J2EE Session Variables option on the ColdFusion Administrator Memory Variables page. The J2EE session management mechanism creates a new session identifier for each session, and does not use either the CFToken or the CFID cookie value.

Comment: FYI, that quote is poorly worded and gives a false sense of security.  It's missing the word "browser" in the last sentence.  "...J2EE session management mechanism creates a new session identifier for each browser session...".  So using jsessionid potentially reduces time in which an attack can happen, but is vulnerable to the same attack as the CFID/CFToken cookies/url parameter.

Comment: The text was taken directly from the documentation.  The big difference in my opinion is that using CFID/CFToken those values can actually be passed to your ColdFusion server from the client and ColdFusion respects (uses) them.  With J2EE sessions the server manages the sessions (browser session) without relying on cookies (or url values) passed from the client.

Comment: J2EE sessions still rely on a client side cookie to be set/sent from the browser  _"You can configure ColdFusion to use J2EE servlet session management instead of ColdFusion session management for session variables. This method of session management does not use CFID and CFToken values, but does use a client-side jsessionid session management cookie"_  [link](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/Developing/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec0c35c-7fef.html) You are correct in that a JSessionID cannot be passed via URL, but they can be passed via a cookie and are still respected by browser.

Comment: Yes, I agree with you guys and realize that J2EE sessions are still vulnerable but less-so than CFID/CFToken. Reading further from the excerpt leads you [here](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/Developing/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7c48.html#WS88096532-E1B5-40d6-92CF-41A5E402994B) which provides even further benefits of J2EE session management over ColdFusion session management.  The first case listed for J2EE sessions being _You want to maximize session security, particularly if you also use client variables_