# Coldfusion enabling J2EE session variables vs Coldfusion session variables

Tags: coldfusion, session-variables, coldfusion-8

I turned on the session management in my application and find that session variables (user defined as well as cfid and cftoken) do no persist between pages when I do not turn on 'Use J2EE session variables' in CF Admin. Once I turn on this setting, the session variables persist. Below is the code in application.cfm

```
<cfapplication name="myapp"
    applicationtimeout="#createtimespan(1, 0, 0, 0)#"
    sessionmanagement="yes"
    sessiontimeout="#createtimespan(1, 0, 0, 0)#"
    clientmanagement="no">
```

Both 'Use J2EE session variables' as well as 'Enable Session variables' are turned on in CF admin.

Everything works fine on my personal laptop when I whip up a sample application (I don't have J2EE session variables turned on here).

Can someone clarify why this discrepancy. Why session variables are persisting between pages only when I turn on J2EE session?

Comment: I would recommend not having a space in your application name. I doubt that's causing the error, but just something I'd update.

Comment: @MattBusche: it is the same even after removing the space in the name

Comment: Are you seeing the same behavior in different browsers? The `cfid` and `cftoken` are just cookies that get passed. Not sure why you would be having issues.  Perhaps a restart of the ColdFusion server is necessary after changing that setting (I'm not sure). For what it's worth you should be using Java EE sessions anyway. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12397599/what-are-current-cf9-02-session-cookie-management-best-practices/12409771#12409771

Comment: Thanks Miguel. I am using J2EE session variables now.

Answer (score 1):

check out your Global session timeout settings in the CFIDE admin page.

this will always override every settings in all the Applications.

Comment: _this will always override every settings in all the Applications_ - Not if you have enabled per-application settings on the Settings page of the ColdFusion Administrator. Then the opposite is true; settings in the Application.cfc file override the administrator settings.