# Using ColdFusion's SESSION scope in a subdomain - Internet Explorer behaviour

Tags: cookies, coldfusion, session-cookies, coldfusion-9

I've got a ColdFusion 9 application set up on a certain domain example.com, 
and another one set up on a subdomain of it, subdomain.example.com.

On Application.cfc, both apps have session management enabled and host-specific (not domain-specific) cookies:

```
SessionManagement = true;
SetDomainCookies = false;
```

When using IE, the first visit to **example.com** will set a pair **CFID;CFTOKEN**. But it is a known behaviour that IE will send these cookies to all nested subdomains if the DOMAIN attribute of the cookie is not specified ([Internet Explorer Cookie FAQ, Q3](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2009/08/20/wininet-ie-cookie-internals-faq.aspx)).

Unfortunately, this is the case with the SESSION scope. The following screenshot proves how the cookies sent to/from IE have no domain attribute set:
[image]

This is causing unexpected behaviour, as the application on subdomain.example.com will receive two different pairs of CFID and CFTOKEN (from both example.com and subdomain.example.com). ColdFusion will interpret this as an invalid answer from the browser and will generate a new pair of tokens, thus finishing the previous session.

One solution I can think of is replacing the functionality of SESSION with CFCOOKIE, always specifying the domain, eg. `<cfcookie name="foo" value="bar" domain="#CGI.SERVER_NAME#" />`

Any other solutions?

Or a way of specifying the domain for the cookies that the SESSION scope sets?

Comment: Adding this comment just for info.ColdFusion 10 had a application level setting to specify the domain for the Session cookies (CFID and CFTOKEN). http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/10.0/Developing/WSe61e35da8d3185183e145c0d1353e31f559-7ffc.html

Comment: Are you using J2EE sessions?

Comment: I don't think you can set the domain that way, but you could set `setClientCookies = false` and then use `cfcookie` or `cfheader` to manually set the `CFID` and `CFTOKEN` cookies yourself.  Then you could set the domain value to whatever you like.

Comment: @SeanCoyne: thanks for the idea. Just for reference, what you are suggesting is described here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12397599/what-are-current-cf9-02-session-cookie-management-best-practices. On the other hand, I'm not using J2EE; do you think that would make a difference?

Comment: I always use j2ee sessions. I find it is much more stable.

Comment: We had the same issue. Our main domain set coldfusion to use domain cookies and our server kept resetting the cookies on each page view. We switched ours to j2ee and it fixed the issue. You need to either turn off domain cookies or make one of them use j2ee